# How to mimic the behavior of \ncput* but without the unwanted opaque effect?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

My objective is to have a label with transparent background but any connecting curve passing through the hypothetical box of the label must be hidden.

### Opaque Label

`\ncput*` produces an opaque label as follows. So it does not fit into my objective.

> [image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90}]
        (1,1){A}
        (3,3){B}
    \ncarc[arcangle=-30,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray]{A}{B}
  \ncput*[nrot=:0]{$2\sqrt2$}   
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Transparent Label

The following is my attempt to mimic the code above but with transparent background for the label. However, I failed to mimic the connecting curve.

> [image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90}]
        (1,1){A}
        (3,3){B}
    \ncarc[arcangle=-30,linestyle=none]{A}{B}
  \ncput[nrot=:0]{\psDefBoxNodes{obj}{$2\sqrt2$}}
    \pcarc[arcangle=-30,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray](A)([nodesep=3pt]{A}obj:Cl)
  \pcarc[arcangle=-30,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray]([nodesep=3pt]{B}obj:Cr)(B)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I guess `\ncput*` was made in hurry with a hot needle.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking for.  You can use `ncput` without the star, but you do seem to want a portion of the connecting curve occluded.  Can you provide a fuller example to help see how this issue is interfering with another effect?  Right now it seems you want two conflicting properties:  opacity and non-transparency.

Comment: Or, you can use a `\makebox` as in `  \ncput*[nrot=:0]{\makebox[1em]{$2\sqrt2$}}` and not cover as much with the label.  Or pair up `\makebox` with `\raisebox`.

Comment: @A.Ellett: Shortly speaking, how to make `\ncput*` produce a transparent label but hide the connecting curve inside its hypothetical frame box?

Comment: `pstricks` hides things (like the portion of the connecting curve) by placing opaque boxes on top of each other.  It doesn't simply wipe out the curve.

Comment: @A.Ellett: But the opaque box is what I don't want to get. Converting the PDF to PNG produces a bad result.

Comment: There's probably some kind of elaborate clipping that you can do with the curve.  I'll think about it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @A.Ellett: For a straight connecting curve, I have the solution [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97561/19356).

Comment: It seems to me that you need to define a bezier curve to connect the nodes.  What would be nice is to define a bezier curve from point A to point B but only trace out a portion of it.  You might look at the implementation of `pst-bezier` to see whether this is possible.  I say *implementation* because the documentation does not show you how to do this.

Comment: I've posted a new solution which should do what you want.  My previous solution had a number of short comings, but this version seems to work pretty well.  I've tested under a number of conditions and it seems to handle working with `pst-eucl` very well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've defined a macro for a simple quadratic bezier curve to connect two points.  But, I've also added two parameters to allow you to specify the start and end of the portion of the bezier curve you want plotted.

The command is arguments are

```
 \mybeziercurve[options]{<t-start>}{<t-end>}{<n-start>}{<n-control>}{<n-end>}
```

where

```
t-start    is a value between 0 and 1
t-end      is a value between 0 and 1 (ideally larger than t-start)
n-start    is the first node to be connected
n-control  is a node to control the effect of the bezier curve
n-end      is the second node to be connected
```

There is also a command to place a point along the bezier curve

```
\myputnodeoncurve{<pos>}{<node-start>}{<control-node>}{<node-end>}{<new-node>}
```

where

```
pos  should be a number between 0 and 1

other parameters are as for \mybeziercurve
```

**Please note** that this implementation requires that you're using `pst-eucl` since I'm using `pst-eucl`'s *postscript dictionary*.

## Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@my@bezier@curve}[4]
    {%
            tx@EcldDict begin
            %% x coordinate
            1 #1 sub
            1 #1 sub
                    /N@#2 GetNode 0 mul add     mul
            #1
                    /N@#3 GetNode 0 mul add     mul add mul
            %--
              #1 
            1 #1 sub
                    /N@#3 GetNode 0 mul add     mul
              #1
                    /N@#4 GetNode 0 mul add     mul add mul add
            \pst@number\psxunit div
            %% y coordinate
            1 #1 sub
            1 #1 sub
                    /N@#2 GetNode exch 0 mul add     mul
            #1
                    /N@#3 GetNode exch 0 mul add     mul add mul
            %--
              #1 
            1 #1 sub
                    /N@#3 GetNode exch 0 mul add     mul
              #1
                    /N@#4 GetNode exch 0 mul add     mul add mul add
            \pst@number\psyunit div
            end
    }

\newcommand{\mybeziercurve}[6][]
    {%
        \def\@ParamStart{#2}%
        \def\@ParamEnd{#3}%
        \parametricplot[plotstyle=line,plotpoints=100,#1]
        {\@ParamStart}{\@ParamEnd}{ \@my@bezier@curve{t}{#4}{#5}{#6} }        
    }
%% a macro to place a node on the curve for labeling purposes
\newcommand{\myputnodeoncurve}[5]
    {%
        \pnode( !\@my@bezier@curve{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4} ){#5}%
    }
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0,0)(4,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45,-45},
                PointName={default,default,none},
                PointSymbol={default,default,none}]
        (2,1){A}
        (3,3){B}
        (3,1){C}

    \pstRotation[RotAngle=130,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{A}{C}[D]
    \pstTranslation[DistCoef=-1.5,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{C}{D}{C}[D]

    \mybeziercurve[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.4pt,linestyle=dashed]{0}{0.35}{A}{D}{B}
    \mybeziercurve[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.4pt,linestyle=dashed]{0.65}{1}{A}{D}{B}

    \myputnodeoncurve{0.5}{A}{D}{B}{E}
    \rput(E){$\sqrt{2}$}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Something which looks more like what you want

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0,0)(4,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45,-45},
                PointName={default,default,none},
                PointSymbol={default,default,none}]
        (2,1){A}
        (5,5){B}
        (5,1){C}
\mybeziercurve[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.4pt,linestyle=dashed]{0}{0.40}{A}{C}{B}
\mybeziercurve[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.4pt,linestyle=dashed]{0.60}{1}{A}{C}{B}

\myputnodeoncurve{0.5}{A}{C}{B}{E}
\rput(E){$\sqrt{2}$}
\end{pspicture}
```

Your selection of where to place the *control point* will allow you to better shape the curve.

> [image]

You can add the following to your preamble:

```
%% command to get angle 
\newcommand{\mygetangle}[2]
    {   !
        tx@EcldDict begin
        /N@#2 GetNode 0 mul add
        /N@#1 GetNode 0 mul add sub 
        /N@#2 GetNode exch 0 mul add
        /N@#1 GetNode exch 0 mul add sub 
        exch
        atan
        end
     }
```

And then you can slope the label accordingly using

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0,0)(4,4)
   \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45,-45},
               PointName={default,default,none},
               PointSymbol={default,default,none}]
       (2,1){A}
       (5,5){B}
       (5,1){C}


   \mybeziercurve[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.4pt,linestyle=dashed]{0}{0.40}{A}{C}{B}
   \mybeziercurve[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.4pt,linestyle=dashed]{0.60}{1}{A}{C}{B}

   %% Setting points to get slope of omitted section
   \myputnodeoncurve{0.40}{A}{C}{B}{E1}
   \myputnodeoncurve{0.50}{A}{C}{B}{E}
   \myputnodeoncurve{0.60}{A}{C}{B}{E2}
   \rput{\mygetangle{E1}{E2}}(E){$\sqrt{2}$}
```

\end{pspicture}

> [image]

Comment: Oh my ghost! There are 14 revisions. :-)