# What parameter is available to remove the thin border around \ncput*?

Tags: pstricks, transparency

The objective is to make the background color of the box containing the label transparent.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90}]
        (1,1){A}
        (3,3){B}
    \ncarc[arcangle=-30,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray]{A}{B}
  \ncput*[nrot=:0]{$2\sqrt2$}   
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I use `-transparent white` when invoking ImageMagick's `convert`. Unfortunately there is still a thin yet visible border around the box as follows. Is there any option to remove such an unwanted border?

> [image]

This question is my attempt to solve my other question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97720/19356).

Comment: Can you see the white thin border?

Comment: The existence of this defect really disturbs my mind much.

Comment: I can't see the rectangle with my previewers: TeXWorks, Adobe, Mac Preview.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Of course you cannot see it in PDF viewers as I am talking about the PNG output.

Comment: Do you think this question belongs to TeX.SX. For me it's an issue with ImageMagick. E.g: http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/12/convert-white-to-transparent.html

Comment: In the beginning I thought there is a parameter in PSTricks to solve it. But now after waiting for a couple of miliseconds, I believe that it is no longer related to PSTricks. It is time to delete it. Danke!

Comment: What options do you use to convert the DVI to PNG with ImageMagick? It always turns out really small and unreadable for me.

Comment: @Jake: I converted it from PDF (rather than DVI) to PNG.

Comment: @ClickMe: So `latex` -> `dvipdf` -> `convert -transparent white`?

Comment: @Jake: No. My workflow is `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` followed by `convert ........`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add a background to the image that has the same colour as the box:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)
    \psframe*[linecolor=white](4,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90}]
        (1,1){A}
        (3,3){B}
    \ncarc[arcangle=-30,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray]{A}{B}
  \ncput*[nrot=:0]{$2\sqrt2$}   
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```